# How to add a different color next to textbox in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net

Probably by the title is kinda hard to understand what I meant by that, but I am trying to archive something like this.

[image: img1]

I am trying to add in a textbox that little orange part next to the button.
I tried to create an other div which will be visible when you select the textbox. but didnt work.

any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple like this would do?

```css
button {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button>Browse games</button>
```